# How to fix Responsive form layout

Tags: css, forms, layout, responsive-design

I am building this form: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gFoIG/

and so far I am satisfied. Unfortunately I have some issue that I seem not able to fix.

First of all, I want to enforce the label positions beside their respective inputs. Now the form breaks down easily (with the opera emulator for smartphone and tablet, the privacy label goes below the check, but I want that it stays beside it)

The other issue that I have is that I want it to fall back gracefully when there are small screens, like placing the second image below the first and placing the input controls one below the other and take the full screen width to be bigger and easier to interact with, but so far I only was able to break the layout with my tests.

This issue: the the form layout breaks, the internal control (input, button, etc) go outside the container div. How do I enforce the container to keep everything inside? I've experimented with blocks, floats and whatever, but if the layout breaks, the input boxes usually go outside the gray rectangle.

Last issue: If I insert this form inside an existing website (for example, a page in wordpress) the layout get completely destroyed because influences from the theme style. How do I enforce my style on my form, keeping it isolated from the other styles? I can think of the iframe as a solution, but it is the only one? It is a good practice?

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look [here](http://www.easyresponsive.com).  Its a site I just set up to explain an approach to responsive using a jQuery plugin to manage redoing layout.  I think it could work for your example quite easily.  Also because it can target a container div at any depth in a web page, it could be helpful in the scenario where the layout you want to reflow is inside a 3rd party container (as long as you can run script on the page).